# Difference between using Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server

Is there a practical difference between using Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

I am making a VM of Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with LXDE desktop, and it's very fast with small size on disk, even after full upgrade. It is a great learning tool, as I am building it from the ground up.

Thank you.

Comment: vembutech: your link answered my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... generally speaking, the two distributions differ in that one has a graphical environment, and the other has not.
Also I guess, the kernel is compiled with less modules and optimized for other work. (pointing Ubuntu server)

The server version is more light than the desktop.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your assertion that the kernels are different?

Comment: On ubuntu server 14.04

sudo lsmod | wc -l
59

On Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

sudo lsmod | wc -l
87

Comment: There is no difference between the kernels, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F

Comment: I said that the kernel has more modules, not different kernel.